# Using Paint.setStrokeJoin() and Paint.setStrokeMiter()

Tags: java, android, graphics

I'm curious about what these methods do and how to use them as there doesnt seem to be any details beyond the single sentence descriptions in the Javadocs:

[setStrokeJoin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeJoin%28android.graphics.Paint.Join%29)

[setStrokeMiter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeMiter%28float%29)

Anybody have some example code or a good description?

Comment: After some experimentation I may have answered my own question: looks like these two values really only come into play when dealing with stroke widths > 1 and even then the effect only becomes noticeable with larger widths.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`setStrokeJoin` allows to set three modes how a line join of thick lines is rendered. `ROUND` means a circular section is used to go around the kink, `BEVEL` means another short straigt segment is used perpendicular to the halve angle, and `MITER` means the outer contour of the two joining lines is elongated until it intersects. However, when the angle is really sharp, that point can go very far away, so usually a limit is set that switches from `MITER` to `BEVEL`, if certain sharpness is reached. This limit is controlled by `setStrokeMiter`.

[image]

Comment: Removed link and uploaded the image